# Which of the following maps $T: V \rightarrow V$ are linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials in $X$ with coefficient in $\mathbb{R}$. Which of the following maps $T: V \rightarrow V$ are linear transformation?

1) $T(p(X))=p(X^2)$ for all $p(X) \in V$

2) $T(p(X))=p(X)^2$ for all $p(X) \in V$

3) $T(p(X))=X^2p(X)$ for all $p(X) \in V$

4) $T(p(X))=p(X^2+1)$ for all $p(X) \in V$

My work: I find option 1, 3, 4 are satisfied the condition  for being a linear a transformation, Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

More generally: you can easily prove (try it!) that for any fixed polynomial $g$,
$$C_g(p) = p\circ g$$
and
$$P_g(p) = g\cdot p$$
are linear.

Answer (score 1):

yes, except 2 they are all linear transformations.

for 2 just consider the polynomial $p
_1(x) = p
_2(x)= x$

you can easily check that $T( p
_1(x) + p
_2(x)) \neq T( p
_1(x) )+ T(p
_2(x)) $